# how a make a "non-focusable" java Jframe onscreen keyboard

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, touchscreen

i plan to make a java onscreen keyboard for my windows 8 tablet, now i have a semi transparent always-on-top jframe, the problem is when i start pressing the buttons on it the focus is gained by jframe and the window i am typing on will lose focus and nothing would be typed in there, is there a way that MouseClicked is launched on an non-focused Jframe

Comment: i plan to make an exactly similar keyboard as the stock windows 8 touchscreen keyboard except mine is platform independent custumizeable and semitransparent

Comment: ok great the non-focusable keyboard window works now, the problem is javax.swing does not support multitouch, my effort to create universal touchscreen keyboard is wasted please be warned in advance do use javaFX instead to those to want to do something similar to what i tried to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JDialog for this, not a JFrame since an application should only have a single JFrame.

Then you can use:

```
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
```

Comment: ok this one certainly works i did it by 'JFrame frm= new JFrame(); JDialog jd=new JDialog(null,true); jd.setContentPane(frm.getContentPane()); jd.setFocusableWindowState( false ); jd.setvisible(true);' but this one also woks and hell lot easier this way 'JFrame frm= new JFrame(); frm.setFocusableWindowState( false );'